# How can I symbolicate without archive but have .dsym files?

Tags: ios, debug-symbols, crash-dumps, symbolicatecrash

I have to symbolicate a crash report given to me, however I didn't create the initial archive that was sent to Apple. I do, however, have the .dsym files. Is there a way I can symbolicate the crash file?

Thanks.

Comment: This link has complete instructions on how to use them. http://noverse.com/blog/2010/03/how-to-deal-with-an-iphone-crash-report/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is assuming Xcode 8.2.1 is installed as Xcode.app

Create a new folder on your desktop and call it symbolication 
Put the .dsym files into the symbolication folder

download the crash report
(I used CustomerID.crash as the format of these files)

In the terminal, type:

```
cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash  ~/desktop/symbolication/symbolicgtecrash
cd ~/desktop/symbolication
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
```

Then for each file to symbolicate, type:

```
./symbolicatecrash CustomerID.crash > CustomerID_symbolicated.crash
```

(where CustomerID is the customer id used when saving the crash report)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get the crash logs:-

copy your app dSYM file path using atos command with crash address and execute on terminal:-

Here is the command:-

`atos -arch arm64 -o` `~/Documents/yourApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/yourApp yourExceptionAddress`

**eg:-**

yourExceptionAddress = 0x100048000